# Why is my Elixir function returning a list of lists?

Tags: elixir

I have a struct that is returned by a function `make_struct` exactly like this:

```
%Example.Struct{example: 1, example_again: 2}
```

(i.e. not with brackets like: `[ %Example... ]`), Atleast I think it returns like above, but the function is in a GenServer module and sometimes I have noticed my functions returning a value in a list for some reason I don't comprehend?

I want to return a list of these structs:

```
def foo(data_as_a_list) do
   my_list = []
   for entry <- data_as_a_list do
     my_list = [ make_struct(entry) | my_list ]
   end
end
```

This is returning a list of structs which is each in a list:

```
[
  [ 
    %Example.Struct{example: 1, example_again: 2} 
  ],
  [ 
    %Example.Struct{example: 1, example_again: 2} 
  ]
]
```

I just want:

```
[
   %Example.Struct{example: 1, example_again: 2},
   %Example.Struct{example: 1, example_again: 2}
]
```

Comment: Note if do `Enum.map(data_as_list, fn entry -> make_struct(entry) end)`, then i get my desired list, but I still don't understand why my method above returns a list of  structs each in a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elixir's `for` does not work like most languages' `for` loops - they are comprehensions, not loops. I'd recommend reading [the Elixir guide's page on it](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html).

Comprehensions already return a list (by default; may be another `Collectable` when specifying `:into`), which contains the return of each execution of the `for`'s `do` block. It acts just like a `Enum.map` in simple cases. So you could use either of these for your desired result:

```
def foo(data_as_a_list) do
  for entry <- data_as_a_list do
    make_struct(entry)
  end
end
```

```
def foo(data_as_a_list) do
  Enum.map(data_as_a_list, &make_struct/1)
end
```

I'd consider the second one more idiomatic, since `map`ping functions is extremely common. Comprehensions are mostly for when you have more complex requirements.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things to point out in your code.

1. The idea that what you're doing is assigning `my_list = []` and then using `for` to update `my_list` is wrong.

It's not syntactically wrong, which explains why you don't get an error message, but you're mixing things up.

Things in Elixir are immutable. Which means that in your `for` you're not really updating `my_list` but instead defining new `my_list`s on each "iteration" which are scoped to the `for` construct and have nothing to do with what's outside of it.

When you run something like `a = 2` in `iex` you get back `2`, because the "assignment" returns the assigned value. Or because the result is the last thing that was computed, which is `2`.

With that in mind, your code is equivalent to:

```rb
def foo(data_as_a_list) do
   my_list = []
   for entry <- data_as_a_list do
     [ make_struct(entry) | my_list ]
   end
end
```

> Notice, however, that because things are immutable, every time `[ make_struct(entry) | my_list ]` is read, `my_list` equals `[]`. Both in the updated and in your original code.

2. [`for`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#for/1) in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) is not an iterator construct, but a list comprehension one.

In Elixir, `for` doesn't just loop through things, but produces a list with the result of operations on things. The simplest example would be: `for i <- 1..5, do: i` which produces `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, despite not formally having a list beforehand or updating a list within the `for` construct.

With those two things in mind, if what you want is to get a list calling `make_struct` on every item of `data_as_a_list`, the way you can achieve it with a `for` is with:

```rb
def foo(data_as_a_list) do
   for entry <- data_as_a_list do
     make_struct(entry)
   end
end
```